# In Google Chrome, what is the maximum value for a number input?

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

I have some HTML that allows users to input a number like so:

```
<input type="number" min="1" name="aNumber" value="1" />
```

I noticed that at a certain point, the form data will change how it expresses the input -- i.e. it will change from "1000000" to "9.1e 32" when submitting the data to the server.  But then I noticed at a certain point, it will simply be null.

What is the maximum value the input will still be able to send to the server?

Comment: good guess would be `2147483648` (2^31). _But this guess can be wrong._

Comment: The specs say that a number should be a floating point: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html  Whether this is single precision or double precision remains unclear, especially since the specs aren't very clear on their definition of what a floating point number is http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/datatypes.html#common.data.float

Comment: then - try boundary numbers for 31, 32, 63, and 64 bit floats...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit of research in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/43gW7/.  It turns out that the its a 32 bit float with a range of float +/-3.4028234663e+38.  When it exceeds that range, the value of the input returns null.